# Is it because of if statement?

Tags: php, html, if-statement

this code won't echo out,why??

```
if (isset( $_post['text']) &&isset( $_post['search for']) && isset($_post['Replace'])){
  echo $text= $_post['text'];
  echo $replace= $_post['replace'];
  echo $search= $_post['searchfor'];
  echo $text;
}
?>
<form action='index.php' method ='get'>
  <textarea name='text'  rows=6 cols=30 > </textarea><br><br>
   Search for:<br>
   <input type ='text' name='search for'><br><br>
   Replace with:<br>
   <input type='text' name='replace'><br><br>
   <input type='submit' value='Find & Replace'>``
</form>
```

Comment: obvious reason would be that ..

Comment: change first this> &&isset(  into && isset(

Comment: PHP is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `$_POST` instead of `$_post`

field name should not have spaces in it. so use `search_for` instead
   of `search for`

```
if (isset( $_POST['text']) && isset( $_POST['search_for']) && isset($_POST['replace'])){
    echo $text= $_POST['text'];
    echo $replace= $_POST['replace'];
    echo $search= $_POST['search_for'];
}
<form action='index.php' method ='POST'>
  <textarea name='text'  rows=6 cols=30 > </textarea><br><br>
   Search for:<br>
   <input type ='text' name='search_for'><br><br>
   Replace with:<br>
   <input type='text' name='replace'><br><br>
   <input type='submit' value='Find & Replace'>``
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to combine`$_POST` with a `form` element whose `method` is set as `GET`.

Either change your `form` element's `method` attribute to `POST`, or change `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

### Solution 1

```
<form action='index.php' method='post'>
```

```
if (isset( $_POST['text']) && isset( $_POST['search for']) && isset($_POST['replace']))
```

### Solution 2

```
<form action='index.php' method='get'>
```

```
if (isset( $_GET['text']) && isset( $_GET['search for']) && isset($_GET['replace']))
```

Comment: @iswinky, is it a problem?? :D

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in `$_post['search for']` but you ask later on the code for `$_post['searchfor']`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$_POST` instead of `$_post` . And in `form` you are specifying `method` as `get`, please replace it with `post`.

The final code is..

```
 if (isset( $_POST['text']) &&isset( $_POST['search for']) && isset($_POST['Replace'])){
      echo $text= $_post['text'];
      echo $replace= $_post['replace'];
      echo $search= $_post['search for'];
      echo $text;
    }
    ?>
    <form action='index.php' method ='POST'>
      <textarea name='text'  rows=6 cols=30 > </textarea><br><br>
       Search for:<br>
       <input type ='text' name='search for'><br><br>
       Replace with:<br>
       <input type='text' name='replace'><br><br>
       <input type='submit' value='Find & Replace'>``
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your name in the input box and in php is different this is solution for you

```
if (isset( $_POST['text']) && isset( $_POST['search for']) && isset($_POST['replace'])){
    echo $text= $_POST['text'];
    echo $replace= $_POST['replace'];
    echo $search= $_POST['search for'];
}
<form action='index.php' method ='POST'>
  <textarea name='text'  rows=6 cols=30 > </textarea><br><br>
   Search for:<br>
   <input type ='text' name='search for'><br><br>
   Replace with:<br>
   <input type='text' name='replace'><br><br>
   <input type='submit' value='Find & Replace'>
```

you can also do this by Get method